# Keeping position and size of canvas after panning canvas in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drawing

I'm a newbie, I'm trying to built a visual drawing. I have a canvas and images (images which are created by clicked event) on this canvas.

Code XAML:

```
<Canvas Name="drawing" Background="Black"
            MouseDown="drawing_MouseDown"
            MouseMove="drawing_MouseMove"
            MouseUp="drawing_MouseUp">                             

        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace Panning_used_MatrixTransform
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Point firstPoint = new Point();

        private void drawing_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            firstPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            drawing.CaptureMouse();
        }
        private void drawing_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {

                var lsPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
                var res = lsPoint - firstPoint;
                var element = sender as UIElement;                
                var transform = element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
                var matrix = transform.Matrix;
                matrix.TranslatePrepend(res.X, res.Y);
                transform.Matrix = matrix;

                //udate first point
                firstPoint = lsPoint;
            }
        }
        private void drawing_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            drawing.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to keeping position and size of canvas not change when we panning this canvas (like CAD drawing).

More information:
I want to create the software which allow at the beginning we has nothing on the canvas. When we click a button, we can create some images where we want on the canvas. And clearly at the beginning nothing on it (So nothing on the canvas - XAML code).
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, the manipulation should be performed on the images, instead of the canvas. So when you pan the images, the canvas stays still.

I make a few changes to the XAML code, add another image for testing, also move the event from the canvas to the outer grid, but I do not rename your event handlers so you can compile the new code more easily.

```
<Grid Background="Black" 
      MouseDown="drawing_MouseDown"
      MouseMove="drawing_MouseMove"
      MouseUp="drawing_MouseUp">
    <Canvas Name="drawing">
        <Image x:Name="imgSource" Source="Resources/my-pic.png" 
           Height="100" Width="100" Canvas.Top="30" Canvas.Left="30">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image x:Name="imgSource2" Source="Resources/my-pic.png" 
           Height="100" Width="100" Canvas.Top="230" Canvas.Left="230">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind, I apply the manipulation to each child element of the canvas.

I also remove the `CaptureMouse()/ReleaseMouseCapture()` since I think those two lines are not necessary.

```
private void drawing_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed))
    {
        var lsPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
        var res = lsPoint - firstPoint;

        foreach (UIElement element in drawing.Children)
        {
            var transform = element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
            var matrix = transform.Matrix;
            matrix.TranslatePrepend(res.X, res.Y);
            transform.Matrix = matrix;
        }                

        //udate first point
        firstPoint = lsPoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank kennyzx, but I mean that: I want to pan many objects at the same time on this canvas, not just one image which you mentioned above.

Comment: Hi kennyzx, it's a great code. I'm so sorry, maybe I'm wrong when I didn't provide enough information. I have just updated more information at my question. Please refer.

Comment: Hi there is no need to apologize for that. You can create another (or several) questions, ask one question for one specific problem you want to address. Although I can help you with the new requirement by providing an updated answer,  doing so may make this question hard to follow by other readers, and less useful to them.

Comment: When I run my project, there is a problem at code line: transform.Matrix=matrix; so we can't move objects.

Comment: @Khai what is the problem?

Comment: The program was stopped when I try to pan. Has a error: "InvalidOperationException was unhandled".

Comment: Could you upload you entire project to an online drive and send me the link?

Comment: I forgot repair xaml code so occurred error in my project. Thanks kennyzx